# How do I use Flask to pass a Python function input from an HTML form?

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm working on a web app with Flask but am a novice and am struggling to learn with the documentation. Within a form on a webpage, I have a table of images which are all buttons. I have a Python script, that when passed a specific string will retrieve a small piece of text data from an API. For each cell in the table, my HTML is in this format:

```
<form action="/" method="POST">
    <table>
     <thead></thead>
     <tbody><tr>
        <td><input type=image src="image.jpg" name="SNOWY OWL" value="SNOW"/></td>
        <td><input type=image src="image.jpg" name="BARD OWL" value="BARD"/></td>
        <td><input type=image src="image.jpg" name="BARN OWL" value="BARN"/></td>
     </tr></tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

When passed with the string in the `value=` attribute of `<input>`, a function in my Python script can return what I'm looking for.

Is there a simple method using Flask to take this `value=` attribute and plug it into a Python function, and return the results in text on the webpage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give all the cells the same `name` so that flask can return the `value` like this:

```
  <td><input type=image src="image.jpg" name="SNOWY OWL" value="SNOW"/></td>`
  <td><input type=image src="image.jpg" name="SNOWY OWL" value="BARD"/></td>`
  <td><input type=image src="image.jpg" name="SNOWY OWL" value="BARN"/></td>`
```

Your Python code would be:

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['POST'])
def choose():
    print( request.form.get('SNOWY OWL',None),"CLICKED!")
    return render_template('index.html')
```

How it works is as follows:
`request.form.get("NAMEOFTHECLICKED","WHATTORETURNIFNOSUCHNAME")`

The Following is printed:

> ('BARD', "CLICKED!")
>
> ('BARN', "CLICKED!")

Comment: Thanks, so the form in HTML would remain as it was before, correct?
`<form action="/result" method="POST">`

Comment: Well in your code you didn't have that. If you did you would have to change `@app.route('/result', methods = ['POST'])` instead of `@app.route('/', methods = ['POST'])`